# Efficient way to create like 1000 instance of a class

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile

As a newbie in Kotlin, i want to ask a question. Let’s say that i have class Dog like below,

```
data class Dog(val breed : String, val gender : String, val name : String, val age: Int){}
```

I want to make 1000 instances of this Dog class and add all of instances in an arrayList and later i will use this list in different activities. Imagine that I have an activity which only shows Labradors . So i have to take that arrayList which contains all of my Dogs and filter the breed according to Labrador and show the user.

As i read in articles i think this is an expensive way but i don’t know what the efficient way is to do this. Cause i will create all instances manually like below.

```
fun dogMaker(){
    val dog1 = Dog("example","example","example",1)
    val dog2 = Dog("example","example","example",1)
    val dog3 = Dog("example","example","example",1)
    val dog4 = Dog("example","example","example",1)
    val dog5 = Dog("example","example","example",1)
    //... goes on...

}
```

Could you suggest me an efficient way? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a beginner, don't even worry about trying to optimize this. Just use a FOR loop or initialize the array manually and it'll be fine. If you want to access it in different `Activities`, just make the `ArrayList` a [global variable](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/kotlin/kotlin+global+variable) by declaring it outside of one of your classes. In your case, this means declaring it above `MainActivity`.

The better but more involved way to do it is to store all these items in a [pre-populated database](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/prepopulate). That way, you're not creating an `ArrayList` every time the app runs, you're not taking up memory unnecessarily, and you're only accessing what you need at any given time.

Comment: I really thank you for your answer, i used the first method you mentioned and was really confused that this would not be a proper way to do this. Now, I will learn pre-populated database. Thank you so much again.